# Phonegap barcodescanner faster

Tags: cordova, barcode

Here is my code (and it is working correctly):

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', myDeviceReady, false);
function myDeviceReady() {
    $('#Print').append('Device is ready');
    function Scan() {
        try {
            $('#Print').append('Scanning')
            window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(mySuccess,myError);
        } catch (myCatch) {
            $('#Print').append('catch: ' + myCatch)
            Scan();
        }   
    }
    function mySuccess(result) {
        if (result.cancelled) {
            $('#Print').append('The user cancelled the scan.')
        } else {
            $('#Print').append(result.text);
            $('#Print').append(result.format);
        }
        Scan();
    }

    function myError(error) {
        $('#Print').append('Scanning failed: ' + error);
        Scan();
    }
    Scan();
}
```

Q: Is there any way to poll the scanner any faster?  It takes a few seconds for each scan, and my users have TONS of barcodes to scan.

They used to scan with a wedge to a laptop, but they want to use an iPad now.

Edit:

Maybe what I'm looking for is a 3rd party solution.

Comment: Is phonegap using a zxing plugin to read barcodes? One general question is what barcode format are you trying to read and if there is any way to make the software look for only that code? Barcode software must find the barcode in the image, so the less codes it looks for the faster the performance.

Comment: Which plugin you are using for scanning the codes?

Comment: I am using the barcode scanner plugin from the phonegap plugin site.

Comment: We could really do away with some `$('#Print')` for speed.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your HTML is huge (where getting the DOM node through $('#Print') might take some time), or you're running the app for a long time (in which case the .append might slow down, since it is never cleared), there is nothing wrong with your JavaScript code. In fact, I assume the delay to come from your barcode plugin, not your JavaScript handler.

Before doing anything else, you should check if my assumption is true, and the delay actually happens between your .barcodeScanner.scan() call and the mySuccess()/myFailure() functions.

PhoneGap seems to be using the ZXing (["Zebra Crossing"](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)), which is an established standard. If that's not fast enough, you might want to try alternative libraries:

- [VisionSmarts VSbarcodeReader](http://www.visionsmarts.com/products/vs-barcode-reader.html)
- [ZBar SDK](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/)
- [ShopSavvy Barcode SDK](http://shopsavvy.mobi/developers/)

But it might be that the speed of the autofocus in mobile cameras just isn't good enough for your requirements, and you need laser based hardware. [This link](http://www.iphonelife.com/issues/2012January-February/BarcodeScanning) has a number of products that interface with hardware.

Comment: The HTML is proof-of-concept code, so it is very small. Thanks for the links. I will look into them. There is an adage that "the customer is always right" and my customers want to scan barcodes using their phones and not buy a laser scanner. So whoever can find a way to make that happen will get rich I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the official plugin in cordova http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/

you can make it faster for iOS,

In your XCode project, go to plugins folder, and open CDVBarcodeScanner.mm

change this line:

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
```

for:

```
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
```

Answer (score 1):

In a previous job, I used to work for [CipherLab](http://us.cipherlab.com/catalog.asp), a manufacturer of barcode scanners.

### About Barcode Scanners

First off you need to clarify that it is not the scanner itself that is slow, but rather the application reading it. The scanner performance itself is somewhat a function of price. If you got an inexpensive scanner, it may be slower, spending the money on a nice scanner will increase performance as well as adaptability (ability to read damaged/smudged/dirty barcodes). FYI, most mobile scanners don't have an "auto focus" as @Hazzit suggested, but have a fixed pre-focused lens that is optimized for a certain distance range. If it is an imaging scanner (not a laser) point the scanner at the barcode really close and pull it back until the the scanner reads. End users will quickly memorize the "sweet spot" if they are scanning tons of barcodes. A laser scanner will only read 1D barcodes but will potentially be faster and able to pick up from a wider range of distances.

### About your JS Code

It appears that scanner plugin is executing syncronously (blocks the JS until it gets a barcode). Is there another function in that library that will enable asynchronous use of the scanner? If not, consider looking at other SDK's to see if anyone else allows asynchronous use of a barcode scanner.

Likely somewhat minor, but I'd try to separate your DOM manipulation JS from the scanner code. DOM manipulation is potentially slow depending on the DOM structure, your selectors and what you're doing.

If you could get asynchronous access to the scanner you may be able to uncouple these and do all your DOM manipulation "when possible" if the scanner wasn't blocking while waiting for the next barcode (basically UI updates after you initiate the scanner to accept the next barcode).

### About Keyboard Wedge Scanning

Now the keyboard wedge style scanners are obviously feeding in the data as fast a typing *regardless of whether the app is ready for them or can keep up with the keystrokes*. This will be fast, but lacks application level control.

You can get a bluetooth barcode scanner to work as an HID device (essentially "keyboard wedge" in modern technology) and it will work exactly as mentioned above. Fast, still lacking application level control of the hardware.

Of course many of these bluetooth libraries also support a SPP serial port bluetooth profile which is what gives you the application level control. You can send the scanner commands/configuration and then read back scanned data.

This is where your SDK tools are coming into play. They are simply read/writing to a bluetooth serial port (the scanner) to poll for scanned barcodes. This can potentially be very fast, but will depend on the quality of the SDK. I'm not an iOS programmer and know nothing about that particular platform, but I know in windows their are high level methods of accessing the serial port and low level methods which are much more performant.

Eitherway, you still have the option of going back to the keyboard wedge way of doing thing if you want! Just thought I'd point that out.

Also in this keyboard wedge mode it is common to prefix the scanner data with a shortcut key. Most scanners can insert some extra keystrokes at the beginning or end of the scanned data. For example you might configure your scanner to type `F3+{barcode data}+Enter` and have your page watch for that shortcut, move focus to the correct input box, and then accept the data.

### If all else fails

If all else fails and you just can't get the performance you need... the only way is to write a native app for iOS. While high level tools are great, you'll never quite get the performance of a native app no matter what (for either hardware access or UI performance).

Comment: please note: the phonegap library Phillip is using makes use of the iPad *camera*. He does not seem to be using a laser scanner (or whatever other dedicated hardware device) in his current development setup. His *previous* setup (that the new one is supposed to replace) used a keyboard wedge, I don't think those things exist for iPads. BTW, the scan() call *is* asynchroneous. Other than that your post is correct, it just does not fit with the situation here.

Comment: @Hazzit: Ha, ha, sorry. I didn't realize it was using the camera. My expertise is obviously barcodes - not phonegap/iOS. Still the iPad camera will not have an adjustable focus. The delay will simply be the delay of the camera itself plus any processing (processing will be slow for an image like that and consume iPad CPU cycles). Phillip should look into a bluetooth barcode scanner to really speed that up!

Comment: It seems Apple disagrees http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/ (scroll down to the iSight Camera details, Apple calls that "Auto-Focus") From my experience with barcode apps on mobile phones, it is the focusing time that slows the process down rather than the processing time. But I agree with your suggestion to look at using different hardware.